# How do I unlock non-partitioned space from my HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-usage, partitioning, free

When I installed my ubuntu, I only made partitions for ext4 and swap, but now i have 1.5 Tb of free space and I cant use it. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use Gparted to resize your Ubuntu partition to fill up the free space.

If Gparted isn't installed, open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>) and run `sudo apt-get install gparted`.

Open Gparted by searching for it in Dash (~Start Menu). Select your Ubuntu partition and move your cursor to the edge of it next to the free space. You should be able to drag that edge to fill up the free space of the hard drive. Click Apply in the top left to confirm the change.

If it happens that your swap partition comes between the Ubuntu partition and free space, you'll have to move some things around, which can take a very long time to do. Since it also increases the risk for loss of data, I won't explain this process unless you really want to try it out.

Instead of moving partitions, I recommend just creating a new partition in the free space to act as a data drive. Select the free space in Gparted and click the button to create a new partition in that space. Apply it, and you should now have a ~1.5TB data partition.

If you have any questions, comment.

Comment: Thanks for the help and I gotta say... If I waited for your answer, I would have been ok but i tried reinstalling Ubuntu and it is failing ever since, for days and days in a row. I dont get it. It says "Input/output error while read /dev/sda" or something like that. Never works

Comment: So no important data? If not, you should just completely format the hard drive before installing again. Boot into the LiveCD/USB and start the installation. There should eventually be an option to "Erase Everything and Install Ubuntu." Choose that.

Comment: Yup, no info but it doesn't make it. It stays like an hour trying to make a random partition then says it failed. The problem is probably my HDD.

Comment: @FredericoPinto if it's old, then probably